# How do I get instructions to fully motorize Technic 42006

Tags: technic, motor, instructions, set-modification

I have just purchased the Technic 42006 and would like to make it fully remote controlled.

[image: Technic 42006]

Comment: Is that beyond the instructions listed from pages 34 onwards in book 2?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using [google to search](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=lego%2042006%20motorized%20instructions) for them.

When I did that I found two threads on EuroBricks discussing this - [here](http://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=82309) and [here](http://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=88739). The first thread links to a [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ghyy3yBBW3o) that has downloadable [instructions](http://home.kpn.nl/beer0058/lego/BuildingInstructionsMotorized42006.zip). Note that the instructions are 19MB and the website is fairly slow.